# Can I extract embedded Google maps data from this webpage?

Tags: google-maps

I need the coordinates and data of the points marked on this embedded google maps page:

(The information is public)

[link to webpage](https://www.villamercedes.gov.ar/index.php/2016-06-29-13-19-46/2016-07-02-13-47-29/establecimientos-educativos-de-salud-y-seguridad)

[image: screen capture]

maybe there is a way to view the data in google earth, and extract a kmz file? 
or inspect the page with firefox/chrome inspection tool and find the data file?
or some hack...

Comment: I believe exporting a KML from Google Earth is the most direct way of doing this. or setting up an API to do more or less the same thing with fewer clicks.

Comment: @ Marshall  but how do you find the link to the kml? I tried the inspect tool but can't find any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the full google map by clicking the "View Larger Map" icon in the upper right corner of the map embedded on the page you shared. [Here is the url.](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?hl=en&mid=1N0lIuZK8d0JqXNwJzdI_h5cY2mM&ll=-33.67749273642578%2C-65.4452005&z=13)

In the google map, if you go to the top of the legend and click the three vertical dots, the menu will display the option "Download KML".

Comment: Thank you Lane. It was so simple :) Have a reward https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9diVXTg4Bg